# How to add flv video into joomla mod_custom

Tags: joomla1.5

I used this code to add video into joomla mod_custom. But it is not working. How can I fix it.

```
<div>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.flv">
<param name="movie" value="http://lifeisatripsrilanka.com/video/Cultural_vulture.flv" />
</object>
</div>
```

Comment: No way... You're not still using Joomla1.5 are you?!?  Did it ever work?  Does it not work on all devices/browsers?  Looking for an extension? https://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/flash-management/  There are a few posts in the Joomla Forum if you want to continue researching.

Comment: If you manage to self-solve, be sure to answer your own question and award it the green tick.